# How to use quadratic reciprocity to prove this?

Tags: number-theory

Let $n \geq 2$ be a natural number. Suppose that $p=2^{2^n}+1$ is prime. Use quadratic reciprocity to prove $$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=-1$$

So far I have $${\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)}  {\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)}=({-1})^{\frac{(p-1)}{2} \frac{(q-1)}{2}}=(-1)^{(2^{2^n-1})}=1$$ by quadratic reciprocity how can I conclude that $$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=-1$$ from this.

Comment: If $n \geqslant 1$, what is the remainder of $2^{2^n} + 1$ modulo $3$?

Comment: Would it be remainder $2$? And if so how does this help I'm not seeing how. Thanks!

Comment: What is $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)$?

Comment: Oh I think I get it the remainder is $2$ so $(\frac{p}{3})=(\frac{2}{3})=-1$ so by the formula I posted we must get that $(\frac{3}{p})=-1$.?

Comment: Yes. Often, the law of quadratic reciprocity is more useful in the form $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}}\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$.